# how does php interpret numbers when you add '0' infront

Tags: php

How does the php interpret 026 and 26.

For example :

```
$a = 26;
echo $a; // result 26

$b = 026;
echo &b; // results in 22
```

Also for.

```
function abc() {
    return (int)(0.5+029);
    //return (int)(0.5+29)
}

$bac = abc();
```

it gives "2" and "29" does anyone knows how does return(int) works? and why does (return 029) displays "2".

P.S: Why does it says that my post does not meet quality standards and Things that i tried and proper grammat..????

Comment: An integer is a natural number, so it will remove the decimals. You could use (float). http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you preceed integers with zero in PHP, in that instance, `029`.

It becomes octal.

So when you echo that, it will convert to its decimal form.

Which results to:

```
echo 029; // 2 (decimal)
```

Actually, its here stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Valid octal:

```
octal       : 0[0-7]+
```

Comment: Note that `029` is an invalid octal number, so PHP takes only as much as is valid (`02`) and treats that as the octal value; `026` is a valid octal value, so it's correctly treated as decimal `22`